# Column width removing padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using some styling on my .row because that I need my columns to stack. But it disrupts my padding-right, so that it isn't 20px, as on the left and top. How can I fix this?

You can view it live here: http://nicolajreck.dk/

**Code**

```
.row {
    -moz-column-width: 20em;
    -webkit-column-width: 20em; //This affects the width, and disrupts the padding 
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-gap:30px; 
}
```

**Problem**

[image]

Comment: what is your problem with right padding?please give little bit more info about your problem.Thanx

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](/help/mcve). I doubt this question is answerable without it.

Comment: @Leothelion I've added some more information. It removes the padding of 20px on the right.

Comment: please check in firefox..its looking great..this issue is only appearing in chrome(as i only checked in chrome and ff).

Comment: Check philip answer..it will work sure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `margin: 10px` from `.row > .col-md-4`